# Bootstrap navigation bar on mobile view the button click fails to show the links hidden

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap has this neat feature that collapses the navigation on mobile to three lines button which is you click on mobile shows you the navbar links, it's not working on mine when clicked.

This is the nav code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand font-orbitron" href="/">
        <img src="/static/images/binoculars.png" alt="Logo" class="nav-logo">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExample04" aria-controls="navbarsExample04" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExample">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            
                <li class="nav-item font-abeezee active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/" title="Kenya Professional Safari Guides Association">Home </a>
                    
                    
                </li>
            
                <li class="nav-item font-abeezee">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/about-us" title="About Us">About Us </a>
                    
                    
                </li>
            
                <li class="nav-item font-abeezee">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/gallery" title="Gallery">Gallery </a>
                    
                    
                </li>
            
                <li class="nav-item font-abeezee">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/careers" title="Careers">Careers </a>
                    
                    
                </li>
            
                <li class="nav-item font-abeezee">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/contact-us" title="Contact Us">Contact Us </a>
                    
                    
                </li>
            
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

and the imports

```
<script src="/static/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

for bootstrap 5

also

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

the viewport code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to include jQuery if you are using bootstrap V5.0
As you have written you are using bootstrap version 5 I'm considering you are using bootstrap v5.0

The first error is in your `<button>...</button>` code.

Change

- `data-toggle` to `data-bs-toggle`
- `data-target` to `data-bs-target`

Your `data-bs-target` should be exactly as the `id` of the `div` above the `ul`

Replace your `<button>...</button>` code with the following

```html
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarsExample" aria-controls="navbarsExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
       <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
```